# How could I register an app in Google App Engine programmatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, programmable-completion

I would like to register a new app on my Admin Console programmatically without having to visit the actual Admin Console webpage.

I see there is no way to do it via API?

Can anyone think of any other solution to do it with a script or some other way?

Comment: There is no Provision API for AppEngine, sorry.

Comment: thx @ShayErlichmen, that's why I'm asking some other way of doing it.